# Importing dataset from Stata

Tags: variables, import, dataset, stata, transfer

I am very new to R studio.
I have imported a dataset from Stata.
Even though the variables appear in R, However, it doesn't recognise any of them.

The following has happened to me:

> time = finaltime
> Error: object 'finaltime' not found
> event= GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI
> Error: object 'GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI' not found
> X=cbind (sex BMI_TCR COLD_ISCH_KI SERUM_CREAT finalpra AGE STEROIDS_MAINT induction DIAB dgf timeondialysis DGN_TCR ETHCAT KDPI finalcmv)
> Error: unexpected symbol in "X=cbind (sex BMI_TCR"
>
> Y=cbind ( time, event)
> Error in cbind(time, event) : object 'event' not found
>
> Coxph= coxph(Surv (time, event)~X, method “Breslow”)
> Error: unexpected input in "Coxph= coxph(Surv (time, event)~X, method “"

When I wrote: ls()
It gave me only the name of the dataset so :
ls()
"data_for_analysis"

When I clicked on the name of the datafile in the Environment window, it started to give me a breakdown of the variables in the dataset, finally. However, there was a dollar sign before the name of each variable.

Would the dollar sign affect all my syntaxes and the names of the variables?
How can I use the names of the variables then to write my syntaxes?

Comment: The dollar sign syntax is how RStudio presents column names in a dataset, as to access them you punctuate as  `ds$col_name`, where df is the name of your "dataset" object in your global environment. This is different than Stata where you (generally) have access to one dataset at a time and do not need to indicate where to look for the column/variable. I am guessing `finaltime` is a column in your dataset?

Comment: When I typed: time(data$finaltime). This worked. However, when I typed:                              event(data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI)
Error in event(data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI) : could not find function "event"
> status(data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI)
Error in status(data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI) : 
  could not find function "status"
> help.search(survival)
Error in help.search(survival) : object 'survival' not found
 I am not sure why R cannot recognise the function "event" or status. I would appreciate your help